# ValueError: TimeSeriesOutput does not support setting output_format or options

Tags: time-series, palantir-foundry

I am trying to create a time series as below but running into ValueError: TimeSeriesOutput does not support setting output_format or options.
I could not find any details or hints in the available documentation.

```
from transforms.api import transform, incremental, Input, Output 
from transforms.timeseries import TimeSeriesOutput

@incremental(semantic_version=1)
@transform(
    output_dataset= TimeSeriesOutput("/path/to/output/dataset"),
    input_dataset=Input("/path/to/input/dataset"),
)
def my_compute_function(output_dataset, input_dataset):
    output_dataset.write_dataframe(
        input_dataset.dataframe('added').repartitionByRange('seriesId').sortWithinPartitions('seriesId', 'timestamp'),
        output_format='soho', options={'noho': 'true'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeSeriesOutput` is part of the a transforms-addons library which provide a collection of utility methods to help with a variety of pipeline tasks. If you control click on the `TimeSeriesOutput` you should be able to see the logic that backs it. Which does include the code that generates error you are hitting here.

```
if output_format != 'soho' or options is not None:
    raise ValueError('TimeSeriesOutput does not support setting output_format or options')
options = dict({'Noho': 'true'})
```

Your exception looks like a bug on the library, since noho is set to true within the same function. So a quick fix for you here is to just to set `options=None`